# Is polynomial convexity a topological invariant?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Is the property of being polynomially convex a topological invariant?

In other words, let $M$ and $N$ be two homeomorphic, compact subsets of $n$-dimensional complex Euclidean space, and assume in addition that $M$ is  polynomially convex.

> Is $N$ necessarily polynomial convex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is *no*.

In fact, Kallin has shown in **[Kal64]** that the union of three disjoint closed balls is polynomially convex, but the union of three disjoint closed polydisks needs not to be polynomially convex.

Actually, it turns out that polynomial convexity is not even preserved by (real) linear transformations. For instance, Khudaĭberganov and Kytmanov have given in **[KK84]** an example of three closed disjoint ellipsoids the union of which is not polynomially convex.

**References**

**[Kal64]**  E. Kallin: *[Polynomial convexity: The three spheres problem](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-48016-4_26#page-1)*, Proc. Conf. Complex Analysis (Minneapolis, 1964), Springer, Berlin, pp. 301–304, doi:10.1007/978-3-642-48016-4_26.

**[KK84]** G. Khudaĭberganov and A. M. Kytmanov: *An example of a nonpolynomially convex compact set consisting of three non-intersecting ellipsoids*, Sibirsk. Mat. Zh. 25 (5) (1984), 196-198 (in Russian).

Comment: Thank you very much for  your complete answer. I thank you too  for  your help on revision of my post.

Comment: Is there a  topological  circle in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ which is  polynomial  convex?

Comment: By "circle" you mean $\{z \, \colon  \, |z| \leq 1\}$? If so, yes: any compact, convex set of $\mathbb{C}^N$ is topologically convex.

Comment: @Ferancesco  By  topological circle I  mean  a  subset  of  $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ which is  homeomorphic  to  $\mathbb{T}^{1}=\{z : |z|=1 \}$.

Comment: I'm not an expert. However, it seems to me that by Stone-Weierstrass approximation any compact subset $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ should give a polynomially convex subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, where $\mathbb{C}^n = \mathbb{R}^n + i \mathbb{R}^n$. So the usual circle $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ should provide the desired example in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: @Ferancesco  Thank you for this interesting point: If  $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is  compact then its  convex hull is a compact  convex  subset  of  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ so its  convex hull is  polynomially  convex. Then for  every point $a\in \mathbb{C}^{n} \setminus \mathbb{R}^{n}$ there is  a  polynomial $f$ such that $|f(a)|> sup |f|$ on $K$.

Comment: and  for  $a\in \mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus K$, as you said ,the  Weierestrass theorem, works.

Comment: Good. So you are saying that my example is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, Not only your example about  circle  but also your  general statment is  correct: every compact set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is  polynomialy convex in $\mathbb{R}^{n}+i\mathbb{R}^{n}$. So the next question: Assume that $\phi$ is  a  homeomorphism of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$  such that For  every compact polynomialy convex set $K$, $\phi(K)$ is  polynomialy convex. Does this imply that $\phi $ is  a scalar  map  $\lambda Id$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Of course not. Any linear (over $\mathbb{C}) transformation preserves polynomial convexity. Moreover, a polynomial map, obviously, also has this property. I don't know, if there are not polynomial maps with the same property.